# How do I implement an infinite loader properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to implement an infinite loader for my list of items. I have set up a logic that in my component. Below is the logic I have implemented in the component.

```js
import Text from '../../../Text/Text';
import styles from './DatasetPopOut.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect , useRef} from 'react';

const DatasetPopOut = ({ datasetList, changeDataset, selectedDataSet, fetchMoreDatasetItems}) => {
  
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const myscroll= useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFetching){
    
    }
  }, [isFetching]);

  useEffect(() => {
    myscroll.current.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    return () => myscroll.current.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, []);

  function handleScroll() {
    if (
      myscroll.current.scrollTop + myscroll.current.clientHeight >=
      myscroll.current.scrollHeight
    ) {
      setIsFetching(true)
      fetchMoreDatasetItems();
    
  }
}

return(
  <div className={styles.datasetPopoutWrapper} ref={myscroll}>
```

I am not sure how to write my `isFetching()` function. The data comes from `fetchMoreDatasetItems` passed.  The data of the list is from the `datasetList`. Below is my function I'm passing from the parent component.

```js
fetchMoreDatasetItems=() => {
    const {  dispatch , routeProps: { match: { params: { Aid } } } } = this.props;
    if (Aid) {
      this.props.dispatch(loadDatasetList({
      Aid,
      datasetPage: 0,
      datasetPageSize: 3,
    }));
  }
  
  
  <TableActionList
   datasetList,
   fetchMoreDatasetItems: this.fetchMoreDatasetItems,
              />
```

`TableActionList` is the child component where the infinite loader logic is shown in the first code snippet. I am not sure of how to set the page size of the list to a specific number and then concatenate the rest of the data after we reach the bottom. I know that logic has to be in the `isFetching()` function but I am not sure of how to pass the data from the parents component to the child and create the function. Can anyone help me?